# is it possible to add PHP script in Blogger

Tags: php, javascript, blogger

I am new to blogger and  want to ask is it possible to add php script to blogger to make some application.
if yes then how ? 
If not then what is its replacement ?

I want to add a simple application with form submission.

Comment: guess not! Also off topic ;)

Comment: I will be very grate full if u help me out 
i want to make email app but i don't know blogger supports what or i have to buy some web hosting which supports PHP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't run PHP on blogging services like Blogger, Wordpress.com, Tumblr, etc. You'll need a proper web host.

Comment: i think blogger supports javascript 
is it possible to submit form with JS only of email app

Comment: No. You can't send e-mail with client-side JavaScript. C'mon - you can get PHP hosting for like $2/month if you want to try things out.